# Класс, свойство которого - вектор объектов класса, свойство которого - вектор double

Tags: stl, c++

eva.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "neuron.h"
#include "net.h"

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    system("CLS"); //Очистка экрана

    neuron tmp;
    tmp.add_weight(0.444);
    net neuro_net("eva.bin");
    neuro_net.add_neuron(tmp);
    neuro_net.save();

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

neuron.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>
using std::vector;

class neuron
{
private:
    vector<double> weights;
public:
    neuron();
    virtual ~neuron();
    void add_weight(double &);
    void add_weight(double);
    vector<double> get_weights();
};
```

neuron.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "neuron.h"


neuron::neuron()
{
}

neuron::~neuron()
{
}

void neuron::add_weight(double & weight)
{
    weights.push_back(weight);
}

void neuron::add_weight(double weight)
{
    weights.push_back(weight);
}

vector<double> neuron::get_weights()
{
    return weights;
}
```

net.h

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "neuron.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

using namespace std;

class net
{
private:
    vector<neuron> hidden_layer;
    string file;
public:
    net(const string &);
    virtual ~net();
    void save();
    void add_neuron(neuron);
};
```

net.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "net.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

using namespace std;

net::net(const string &path)
{
    file = path;
}

net::~net()
{

}

void net::save()
{
    try
    {
        ofstream out(file, ios::binary | ios::out);

        if (!out) 
            throw new exception("File initialization error");

        int hidden_layer_size = hidden_layer.size();
        out.write((char*)hidden_layer_size, sizeof hidden_layer_size);
        for (auto neuron : hidden_layer)
        {
            out.write((char*)neuron.get_weights().size(), sizeof neuron.get_weights().size());
            for (auto weight : neuron.get_weights())
            {
                out.write((char*)&weight, sizeof weight);
            }
        }
        out.close();
    }
    catch (exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << endl;
    }
}

void net::add_neuron(neuron new_neuron)
{
    hidden_layer.push_back(new_neuron);
}
```

В отладчике данный код валится при вызове метода net::save(), а именно строчки, где идет получение размера hidden_layer, со следующей ошибкой:
[image]

Но на самом деле, полагаю, ошибка еще раньше, т.к. после добавления объекта в вектор hidden_layer в методе net::add_neuron размер hidden_layer становится неизвестен (???).
Так в чем же ошибка? Что я делаю не так? Помогите разобраться.

Comment: Через 2 часа до пк доеду, погляжу. Тебе к спеху?

Comment: @Андрей Таланин, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Удалось собрать этот код под линуксом, нашел ошибки сразу.

Первая ошибка в строке

```
out.write((char*)hidden_layer_size, sizeof hidden_layer_size);
```

в этом месте в файл записываются данные по адресу, который хранится в hidden_layer_size, а там явно не адрес храниться. Нужно добавить `&`.

```
out.write((char*)&hidden_layer_size, sizeof hidden_layer_size);
```

аналогичная проблема и в строке

```
out.write((char*)neuron.get_weights().size(), sizeof neuron.get_weights().size());
```

Я не сильно разбирался и записал ее проще:

```
int sz = neuron.get_weights().size();
out.write((char*)&sz, sizeof sz);
```

после этого код скомпилировался и даже отработал (без падений) и даже сгенерировал файл eva.bin с какими то данными. Насколько они правильные - я не знаю.

Answer (score 0):

Выглядит, как будто hidden_layer нормально не инициализировался. Для страховки стоит добавить вызов его конструктора в конструктор net:

```
net::net(const string &path):hidden_layer(),file(path)
{
}
```

Но по идее конструкторы по умолчанию для членов класса должны подставляться компилятором автоматически. Может быть, конструктор класса net не запускается? Я бы в него поставил точку останова или вывод отладочной информации, чтобы убедиться, что инициализация проходит полностью.

Update: сначала не заметил код из eva.cpp. Конструктор класса net должен запускаться, так что остаётся предположение, что компилятор не добавил конструктор по умолчанию. Вообще обязательный вызов конструкторов членов класса, IMHO, должен стать привычкой. Один компилятор их сам добавит, а другой - нет.